Why does the condition_variable destructor hang this program?
I have a program, which I distilled into this short MRE:
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
void test(){
    std::unique_lock lk(mu);
    cv.wait(lk);
}
int main(){
 std::thread(test).detach();
 sleep(3);
}

If you run it, you will note that it hangs, even accounting for the 3s sleep. If you run the program under gdb, and interrupt it while it's hanging, you will see that it is blocked at pthread_cond_destroy. If you look at the backtrace at this point, you will see that it is due to cv's destructor.
I'm not completely sure why it happens.

A side note: detaching a std::thread is [almost] always wrong.

Do you know what your cv.wait(lk); does?

What is the purpose of this code ? The thread is waiting on a cv which is never notifyied anywhere.

From this std::condition_variable destructor reference: "It is only safe to invoke the destructor if all threads have been notified." You don't notify the condition variable, therefore its destruction is not safe.

@DrewDormann It waits for a notification --- in the actual program, there are notifications.

@Someprogrammerdude I'm writing a library, so I don't have control over when the program exits.

Then please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Also note that when the process exits all threads will be terminated, even the detached ones.

@Someprogrammerdude What do you mean? The problem is that upon exit, the destructor hangs, which this snippet shows. At the time of exit, there is (likely) no notification occuring.

You must notify all threads waiting on conditional variable or result of destructor invocation is undefined. Oh.. and having global state in library which reqiures a proper closure without having proper routine which would ensure such closure is wrong.

@Someprogrammerdude depends on certain things and platform.. I encountered cases where it doesn't on Linux! usualy related to handling of signals. Oh progam looks like it was stopped, alright. Only there is a thread in memory having a hard 100% CPU loop.

In this case the order in which things happens at process exit is kind of relevant... What probably happens is that the attempted destruction of the cv object happens before the thread is terminated by the OS. This is the likely order, since it's the OS which in the end terminates the process and all its threads, while destruction of global variables happens while the process is still running (by code compiler-specific outside of the main function). But there are no guarantees that this will always happen, on all systems. If it was the opposite, then your program could seem to work.

Something like this fixes your problem. Even so you still have to make sure nothing tries to wait on the wrapper after it is destructed.

"in the actual program, there are notifications" If you are not showing us "the actual program" that your question is about, we can not help you.

@DrewDormann The "actual program" is much longer, and most of it has nothing to do with the problem. The reason what I left out a notification here, is that in the program, a notification does not occur anytime near the destruction of the conditional variable.

Thanks @Caleth. Using your code, I was able to find a solution. If you can move your comment into an answer (or modify your answer to add it), I'll accept it.

@DarkRise creating a [mre] would be what's appropriate.

Thanks to a comment by Caleth, I was able to find a solution:
class wrapper {
    std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable cond_var;

    public:
    std::atomic<bool> abool=false;
    void not(){
        cond_var.notify_all();
    }

    void wait(){
        std::unique_lock lk(mutex);
        cond_var.wait(lk);
    }
     ~wrapper(){
         abool=true;
         not();
     }
};

After the condition variable unlocks, I just check whether abool is set to true --- if so, I exit.

It is undefined behaviour to destruct a condition variable that is blocking a thread.

~condition_variable();
Preconditions: There is no thread blocked on *this.

[thread.condvar]
Deadlocking is one possible symptom of undefined behaviour.

...and although undefined behavior can produce almost any result, in this case deadlock is pretty much the obvious result you'd expect. Not guaranteed to happen, but shouldn't come as a surprise at all.

As @Caleth has already pointed out, your code currently has undefined behavior (and although he didn't point it out, a deadlock is probably the most obvious result of this particular undefined behavior).
I've yet to see a case where a detched thread really made sense. As a general rule, I'd plan on joining all child threads before the program exits.
I usually end up using cv.wait_for instead of cv.wait, and I usually use a jthread, so I have a stop token to tell the thread to exit. If you need compatibility with compilers that predate jthread, you can use an std::atomic<bool> for the same purpose.
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::literals;

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
void test(){
    std::unique_lock lk(mu);

    // in real life, the lambda would check whether there's some work
    // to do. If it returns false, we'd check the stop token to see
    // whether the thread should exit.
    if (!cv.wait_for(lk, 2s, [] { return false; }))
        return;
}

int main(){
    auto child = std::thread(test);
    sleep(3);
    child.join();
}

I believe this has defined behavior, and should exit after about 3 seconds (though sleep(3) really means "sleep for at least 3 seconds", so it could be longer, especially if the system is heavily loaded).
